# All buttons in Microsoft's Edge browser are gone, as well as in all Metro apps

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, windows-10-v1607, microsoft-edge

I'm not sure how to fix this. Take a look at this screenshot of Microsoft Edge browser on my Windows 10 Lenovo tablet:

[image]

As you see all buttons and controls are gone. The same by the way happens with any other Metro app.

Any ideas will be appreciated. I tried looking in Control Panel but all previous / familiar settings are reshuffled... and I'm totally lost!

Comment: update the GPU drivers

Comment: @magicandre1981: I don't think it has a GPU. It's a Lenovo tablet.

Comment: GPU = graphic chip. each device has a graphic chip otherwise you don't get any picture on screen ;)

Comment: does updating the driver fixed it?

Comment: @magicandre1981: No. There's no GPU driver for that tablet.

Comment: which tablet do you use? post the complete model name

Comment: @magicandre1981: Lenovo IdeaTab Lynx

Comment: ok, this tablet uses an Intel Atom Z2760 and this GPU is incompatible with Windows 10 and is known to cause this issue you see